# Css in play doesn't load header

Tags: css, playframework, playframework-2.0

Hey guys I am trying to set a header through my CSS file, but somehow it doesn't work..

```
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(28, 36, 65, 0.93);
    background: url('/assets/images/header.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I tried it with this url or with '../images/header.jp' but both don't load the image. If I manually navigate to www.myurl.com/assets/images/header.jpg the file is there and rendered.

Whats wrong here?

Comment: Image paths in CSS are relative to the CSS file itself. How does your directory tree look like? where is the CSS file located?

Comment: my css is at /public/stylesheets (default of playframework) and my header is at /public/images/header.jpg

Comment: well then where did "assets" come from?

Comment: Your css would have better style if you did `background: rgba(28, 36, 65, .93) url('/assets/imges/header.jpg') cover;`.

Comment: assets is coming from the play framework, its the place where every image etc gets rendered

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a `/`

Try this:

`background: url('/assets/images/header.jpg');`

Comment: No sorry I forgot to write it down. I tested it with background: url('/assets/images/header.jpg'); as well as background: url('../images/header.jpg'); both didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your main css file actually is. 
Try to change it to:

```
background: url("/assets/images/header.jpg");
```

Or take a look at this quick guide:
https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this. If there will be any path issue then you may try adding `../../path-to-image/img.png`

```css
.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(28, 36, 65, 0.93) url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>
  <h1>Ihara</h1>
</div>
```

Do comeback if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I am sorry I messed something up....I edited the copy of my actual css...everything worked when I did it on the actual css file.

I am sorry about that